# history.pushState() is not displaying the correct URL

Tags: jquery, html, pushstate

I'm using jQuery and PHP, I have a problem with `history.pushState`.

When I click the anchor tag or the link once the URL in the browser looks like this `www.example.com/index.php/home/viewer/id`

When I click the link again the URL in the browser looks like this 
 `www.example.com/index.php/home/photo_viewer/index.php/home/viewer/id`
which is not correct.

I want the URL in the browser to be `www.example.com/index.php/home/viewer/id`

How do I solve this problem?

```
<a href="index.php/home/viewer/ $row['id'] " Onclick="viewer(this); return false;"> id </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function viewer(link){
       var ajax_data ={ajax:'1'};

       $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: link,  
    data: ajax_data,
             success: function(html){

                  $("#viewer").html(html); 

    window.history.pushState(null,null, link);

    e.preventDefault();
     }});
        return false; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because your URL is relative. You have to make it absolute by prepending a slash:

```
href="/index.php/home/viewer/..."
//    ^
```

A relative URL always specifies a resources that is *relative* to the current resource, i.e. the path is just appended to the current path. See also the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method):

> The new URL does not need to be absolute; if it's relative, it's resolved relative to the current URL.

**Update:** Although it does make a big difference, access the `href` attribute of the link, instead of the link itself: `link.href`.

Comment: @user: You said the you edited the code but the URL still looks the same... it will work with an absolute URL.